# Using builder pattern to create a strongly-typed, diverse Record (like Redux Toolkit does)

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to write code that uses a builder pattern to dynamically construct strongly-typed records/maps along the lines of what Redux Toolkit does with their `createReducer` function.

In other words, for an arbitrary set of base records, e.g.:

```
type BaseRecord = {name: string} & Record<string, string | number>

const recordA: BaseRecord = {
    name: "recordA",
    fooString: "foo",
    fooNumber: 6
}

const recordB: BaseRecord = {
    name: "recordB",
    barString: "bar",
    barNumber: 2,
    barSecondString: "bar2"
}
```

I want to have a construction function that uses a builder callback to put them into a strongly typed map, like so:

```
const newRecordMap = createRecordMap(builder=>{
    builder.addRecord(recordA).addRecord(recordB)
})
```

where `newRecordMap` ends up typed as

```
{
  recordA: typeof recordA
  recordB: typeof recordB
}
```

and NOT some type-erased version like: `Record<string, BaseRecord>`

I've tried various versions of the following:

```
type RecordMapBuilder = {
    addRecord: <T extends BaseRecord>(record:T)=>RecordMapBuilder
}

function createRecordMap(builderCallBack:(builder:RecordMapBuilder)=>void){
    const recordMap = {}
    const builder:RecordMapBuilder = {
        addRecord: (record)=>{
            recordMap[record.name] = record
            return builder
        }
    }
    builderCallback(builder)
    return recordMap
}
```

The problem is basically the typing of `RecordMap` (as far as I can tell).  If it's narrow--as above--then the assignment in the `addRecord` function won't work.  And if it's broad than the types passed in get erased.

I've studied the RTK code for [createReducer](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/createReducer.ts) and [mapBuilder](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/packages/toolkit/src/mapBuilders.ts), and they seem to be able to enable this type of inference, using their `CaseReducers` type (line 65 in the first link), but I can't follow why that works or how to make it work in my simplified example.

[Here's a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WKINjRnGplMSVTP3rThtD0zswDI3MWAVSItRGONrM6eVFSHaAKRYQhyEY0A5FEeAUCNal4AVbBN0tYj+P1IUskUcw7HmWiMTjWc31C0AkAik9oqE2LPyMylqRUJyXLwGhIDIBLHSFAAvFLILS4S3RCOKZihTouCAA) illustrating the issue.

How can I get type inference to work correctly here?

### EDIT

I'm going to put a bounty on this question stating that I'm looking for a canonical answer.  I find I'm somewhat frequently looking for a pattern like this, i.e., some way to build up, programmatically, a strongly typed Record (or Map) where each Record has its own type that extends some generic type, but the ultimate Record is not a type erased Record but is as precise as if you had manually written out the Record.  I believe this is possible because Redux Toolkit uses what appears to be this pattern in several places, and the question as phrased above was meant to illustrate the difficulties I've had implementing an RTK-like solution.

That said, I'm open to any answer that provides the canonical way to build up a strongly-typed, diverse record in TypeScript of the kind explained in the question above.

### EDIT 2

@Алексей Мартинкевич's answer had some helpful insights (and it may be the best there is), but it requires using a class and a number of assertions.  I've been trying to get it to work with a functional approach, but I still can't get the generic inferences right.
Currently, I'm stuck with:

```
// Base types and builder function
type BaseRecord<Name extends string> = {name: Name} & Record<string, string | number>

type RecordName<Rec extends BaseRecord<string>> = Rec extends BaseRecord<
  infer Name
>
  ? Name
  : never;

type ToMapItem<Rec extends BaseRecord<string>> = {
  [key in RecordName<Rec>]: Rec;
}

type RecordMapBuilder<TRecordMap extends Record<string, BaseRecord<string>>> = {
    addRecord<Name extends string, BR extends BaseRecord<Name>>(record: BR):RecordMapBuilder<TRecordMap & ToMapItem<BR>>
}

function createRecordMap<TRecordMapBuilder extends RecordMapBuilder<any>>(builderCallBack:(builder:TRecordMapBuilder)=>void){
    const recordMap:RecordMapBuilder<{}> = {} 
    const builder = {
        addRecord<TName extends string, TBaseRecord extends BaseRecord<TName>>(record:TBaseRecord){
            (recordMap as any)[record.name] = record 
            return builder
        }
    }
    builderCallBack(builder)
    return recordMap as TRecordMapBuilder
```

At [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQC4E8AOtqkgOwCagEYCuAlgDY6wBOoAZoVgMYLED2WAsAFDJoQywAlWAxaUcAHgBykALbxYADwSxcGaAkrEsAcwB8oALygA3llmwAXKGlyAvqABkoISLHj1mnQBpQHrdtAAH1AsQhl8Kl0uLh54F1EcG1hxF1BFZVU%20OHi3Px1dfSNU9JUcDChs4QTxLlBQLRoqa3MuKM46gH5muVrQKyxYADcqAG5o7lR4ABUWAFlIFABJZRkU4TSlUvL%20HIk8vUKTXoBtAGtYJHqsZyqxJLWGXQBdKxcxzltx2JvXHHmUcAkchUcRTXb-DYZMo-ar7HwVQS3PYafwFQ7GXp1SA4HC7KTmSFbXwo7wQASEzIIvFJAoACkoSKs4AEAEoLOCFoCyBRKKCOShHKAZv9lrBVsyClxPpwuHRGMw2KAGAzIMp%20Xykf8ucDqCVMvztTzxNgkHSiNyqABhSCkUhQBinCy0806ixgzWcoE8lkGXSDFjEHAsjHtOpKtjqUAM37-dkegFekHGWzo%20yY8NYSMunmGI6hsNh7G4pGgpIU6FwoVUpHl7aVX6l8x06MJN3V37B9MFgv0%20OYDAmlnHFtiAB0ZjkT1zI7wXe7dQZCEIlGu2aoc7q0oLW7Da8o1tt9tOzsTlBZ6cXy%20uM4hMCFBtPUvGIFAABF0MQGXhCHACJcRJmYTrjKnAAZGM4AIK5iGBYTpYoAAESQQhXjpjQLAsAAyiS2hWAh6EsChaEYZIYQRJQVgAGxPiBYEIFGSLgNB6ZwXhM7gER%20YEJAlDYZ4uGIfgPGcQWQmUKR4RUFYABMqFcWJmFVLgfH%20HhYnSQhNFcC%20iygAA7tg9EDHp-KICwBDwK40YIKQlweGw2i2Ygkw4FwdEhLAJl9kYyqwKqiIxgsJ4WpQvowbup6jkWuy9r8EEslFOIxex54fKlbkRiwpCwKOpAsNotLGfyo6QalYFZTleUFUV8YlYxLJAA).  What am I missing? Apologies if I'm being picky, but this is a bounty question for a canonical answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general to achieve something like that you need to use generics.

Let's start with `BaseRecord` type. Original version lost lot's of information. You need to know each record name in order to construct the map. Also, when you assign `const foo: BaseRecord = { /*...*/ }`, `foo`'s type is reduced to `BaseRecord` and all information about exact field names is lost.

There are two ways to deal with it. First is to avoid `BaseRecord` type when declaring records:

```js
const example = {
  name: "foo",
  bar: 0,
  baz: "",
} as const;
```

This is a simple way but it has some downsides. Object becomes `readonly` which might or might not suit you. And there is no check for incorrect values.

```js
const example = {
  name: "foo",
  bar: 0,
  baz: {},
} as const;
// This is fine too.
```

Of course the second object will still give you typescript error when you use it somewhere `BaseRecord` is expected.

And the other way is to use generics

```js
type BaseRecord<Name extends string> = { name: Name } & Record<
  string,
  string | number
>;

// In this case we cannot simply declare variable, so there is a simple helper
function makeRecord<Name extends string, Rec extends BaseRecord<Name>>(
  rec: Rec
) {
  return rec;
}

const r1 = makeRecord({
  name: "A",
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: "3",
});
```

Now the main idea for builder is the following:

```js
// Simple helper to get Name from BaseRecord
type RecordName<Rec extends BaseRecord<string>> = Rec extends BaseRecord<
  infer Name
>
  ? Name
  : never;

// Another helper to convert Rec<Name> to { [Name]: Rec[Name] }
type ToMapItem<Rec extends BaseRecord<string>> = {
  [key in RecordName<Rec>]: Rec;
};

// We store all records in this ResultMap generic argument
export class RecordMapBuilder<ResultMap extends Record<string, BaseRecord<string>>> {
  private map: ResultMap;

  constructor(map: ResultMap) {
    this.map = map;
  }

  // Each time we call addRecord we add new item to the generic argument
  addRecord<Name extends string, Rec extends BaseRecord<Name>>(
    record: Rec
  ): RecordMapBuilder<ResultMap & ToMapItem<Rec>> {
    // Unfortunately this implementation is not type safe internally
    // Perhaps typecast can be avoided if we return `new Builder` instead
    // But I guess it would be a bit of an overkill 
    (this.map as any)[record.name] = record;

    // Same here
    return this as RecordMapBuilder<{}> as RecordMapBuilder<
      ResultMap & ToMapItem<Rec>
    >;
  }

  build() {
    return this.map;
  }
}
```

Use example:

```js
const r1 = makeRecord({
  name: "d",
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: "3",
});

const r2 = {
  name: "e",
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
} as const;

const map = new RecordMapBuilder({})
  // notice that we don't need makeRecord as we pass object literal directly into addRecord method
  .addRecord({
    name: "a",
    numValue: 123,
  })
  .addRecord({
    name: "b",
    stringValue: "abc",
  })
  .addRecord({
    name: "c",
    numValue: 123,
    stringValue: "abc",
  })
  .addRecord(r1)
  .addRecord(r2)
  .build();

console.log(map.a.numValue);
// Error
console.log(map.a.stringValue);

// Error
console.log(map.b.numValue);
console.log(map.b.stringValue);

console.log(map.c.numValue);
console.log(map.c.stringValue);
```

And finally to implement `createRecordMap` function we'll need another generic.
To correctly infer type of the map we have to return builder from the callback.

```js
function createRecordMap<RecordMap extends Record<string, BaseRecord<string>>>(
  builderCallBack: (
    builder: RecordMapBuilder<{}>
  ) => RecordMapBuilder<RecordMap>
) {
  return builderCallBack(new RecordMapBuilder({})).build();
}

const map = createRecordMap((builder) => builder.addRecord(r1).addRecord(r2));
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgJQgYwPYCcAmAeAOTgFtoIAPYCAOxwSgWCwEtqBzAPigF4oBvKNRIQAXFCKkoAXygAyKKky48AWABQUTQyas2AGnVbtLdlAA+ggK7EARhCzqOAbnXrQkBemw4JEPIqgKKlp6eCRFbzxGE04uXgCgmjpYRBQvZUMtVgAze3FhR0zNAH580iKoMWoIADd7FzU3cGgAFQwAWTgwAEkqYn90QMok0NSI5WjdDjj+CoBtAGsIEChWTyUfYQG0DgBdMUUGqQb1CjBsYCg0ABtEenGcTrAYS2ZrnHtVDS1UBEtr4BPIbBZIPKI6dh6FLhdL4SbsaYVLh8CpgFg1OBUKDELoHCB-AFPE7fTSYajRSxoYDYAAUOLAeIJgK6AEpZiSjFBgAALZgIAB09J42K6DSMUlcHLgOBwYN8wJGxl0UISwxC0LSG0IwmmNIqRiwsLxaAqLON3ieLzeHywAyZQPkbSevQg-UU03ZnK0NJ5fMFXSgiED1BALLmho2-KEpF2woj3mJXs0huAliw1C5vPoQYelte70+fCkXBzsLz1s++qTv3+zLAcigTq6Lrd6A4Vc0zgqEsaHJs+ZwNLZKI5BogqfTmb99LFWh7PfU2Us1CpzAwGZxSzlwgV6vh+nWu+SYU1kV8uoqEeN6mHl-HaYzEaOkrJjCgWAAjMLN6fcDSR0Y0aiFAABEOAgQYHLZBgGBiB+kFGDYcBYGIABMCFaEhABeYggQAzBB6hSCyxKvpcWCocKAFaEBuEQIRHLkGIAAMGGaCALGQTIQZkaR65vkKvDVAA7usFpdFaBZYP+xEVPy0qyrC-4doIwi4XADFJlYxAAGpwNcljAR+qF4Wx0gsnJCkPMpo40WpoE2JpSb7npBnASBcA2GgTmaLJHLyTK1nUV6tGgd5ZmAdYrmGXBJkRVoLn6TFoGeeF3YWf5VlKZ+GVGAFikbDSFG5Vo-L9taQ58eSGDXBA-LXBgbB0l08lRlFSUQCRL78TVdUNU19KtYlbldb2r69fVjXNWAZVtbpHWjeNtWTQNLU2Pyw2GaN6hLX1U2DWgc3RZ1DS7St038odm0nZKS4rsAa4ZmghqYr+jxdNs4n1ok6pgvuUInn9EKxBwep9gO9gAML6dc8BoAsYhg1p5VSeauDllJeBFu2HJstwXC5hJEO2oTYA47eHIpg+UAoza0PXLDcDwzSIliejRMVtJRYsiyZUDpVREvi9VCkzSNK0-YeNcBLWD5dZOVy9lqE8w0QA)

**Edit:**

```js
// Desired use by consumer

const recordA = {
    name: "recordA",
    fooString: "foo",
    fooNumber: 6
}

// Unfortunately this is impossible because of the way typescript infers type here
// recordA: {
//    name: string;
//    fooString: string;
//    fooNumber: number;
// }
// The problem here is that `name` has type `string` and we need it to be `"recordA"`
// This is happening because we can change the name later
// i.e. 
recordA.name = "foo";
// I guess the closest way is the following:
const recordA = {
    name: "recordA" as const,
    fooString: "foo",
    fooNumber: 6
}
// or
const recordA = {
    name: "recordA" as "recordA",
    fooString: "foo",
    fooNumber: 6
}
// This marks the name as readonly property so typescript know it cannot be changed to other value.
```

Now about the builder. Class here is not necessary. The main trick is that `addRecord` returns object with new `TRecordMap` argument. However it is necessary to return builder at the end of the callback. The reason for this is that types of the variables cannot be changed, you can only create new types. You can think of it as pure functions on types. So the only way to get the resulting type is to return it.

```js
type RecordMapBuilder<TRecordMap extends Record<string, BaseRecord<string>>> = {
    addRecord<Name extends string, BR extends BaseRecord<Name>>(record: BR): RecordMapBuilder<TRecordMap & ToMapItem<BR>>
}

type RecordMapFromBuilder<Builder extends RecordMapBuilder<any>> = Builder extends RecordMapBuilder<infer RecordMap> ? RecordMap : never;

function createRecordMap<TRecordMapBuilder extends RecordMapBuilder<any>>(builderCallBack: (builder: RecordMapBuilder<{}>) => TRecordMapBuilder) {
    const recordMap: Record<string, BaseRecord<string>> = {}

    const builder: RecordMapBuilder<{}> = {
        addRecord(record) {
            recordMap[record.name] = record

            return builder
        }
    }

    const res = builderCallBack(builder);

    return recordMap as RecordMapFromBuilder<typeof res>
}

// correctly typed
const newRecordMap = createRecordMap(builder =>
    builder.addRecord(recordA).addRecord(recordB)
)
// or
const newRecordMap2 = createRecordMap(builder => {
    return builder.addRecord(recordA).addRecord(recordB)
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQC4E8AOtqkgOwCagEYCuAlgDY6wBOoAZoVgMYLED2WAsAFDJoQywAlWAxaUcAHgBykALbxYADwSxcGaAkrEsAcwB8oALygA3qCyzYALlDS5oAL6gAZKCEix49Zp0AaUF61tUAAfM0IZfCpdLi4eeDdRHFtYcTdQRWVVPjgEjwCdXX0jNIyVHAwoHOFE8S5QetAtGiobCy5ozgbQAH5WuTqG6yxYADcqAG4Y7lR4ABUWAFlIFABJZRlU4XSlMor+XIl8vSKTAfqAbQBrWCRGrFdqsWTNhl0AXWs3Sc57KbiH9w4JYocAkchUcSzA7A7aZcoAmpHPyVQSPQ4aQKFE7GM6YHA4A5SCyw3b+DG+CACElZFGE5KFAAUlDR1nAAgAlJ80cDQWQKJRIdDls5QPNgWtYBs2YUuL9OLEZgixMCAGKUFgyXnggVa-nU+FCkFg-nibBIQqGCDGlqlLKG3UQpotQ36XqG0BDUYTKZ0RjMNigBjMyDKQ2C7nLB3UW0GiNGvkQs2MogJygAYUgpFIUAYl2sDJT2q5gJ51oFxnsunZhn0ULjUerOM6DREWHUoGZJeWxcR5O0yP2aM8fYtRgrUy6rfbhf5PeVkbL4gr2NxXUg+IOTLRjdXXQancSwPOB7EADpzHI3paTzgJ3v78yEIRKPcZ1Rd-U5V05bipwgO+glpvummbZpAuYFmW7LfLij7PvcN4wjASpAssaoalG4hxCwNAAdAHQ-pwICgAAIugxDMnghBwAQtxTuE77ypwf4AYCACClpNl0F5WKAABEN5sXxmAYH+Pi4jQLAsAAyn21h8ZJLB8eJzb1IpkjhJElDWAAbLKUwsTe4CcbiPHyUZwnIQJaLgMpuL4JAlCyd42jyQ5lB2apBCORpERUNYABMKldO50nVLgzmBG5jkBXx+lMcR7idggpC3HEt7MWw7bDAA7u6RhBrAIaol2KCQamNb2WWp7rgSaJbux7I1Ru9VGeyXDtURYCiFwLG5YaAWWoVxWGuV2o1qcXlwS+BDVbVm6CU182tTZnX2J1vVZSwpCwKepAsNoDL9XGp6LZtbbbbt+2HcdpWnatQA)

Comment: thank you for this answer.  It helped me understand some of the problems with my approach, but I'm still struggling to understand why my functional (non-class) solution won't work.  I edited the question to make that clearer.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Updated answer @sam256

Comment: Thank you!! It looks like you can also do this to type the return:
```
    builderCallBack(builder);

    return recordMap as RecordMapFromBuilder<ReturnType<typeof builderCallBack>>
```

Comment: BTW, in case anyone else goes down this rabbit hole, someone on a TS chat pointed out this isn't really a purely functional approach as the `this` of `createRecordMap` is being mutated.